# How secure page browser cache vulnerability makes web application in secure?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, owasp, penetration-testing

I am using OWASP's ZAP tool for vulnerability scanning, it shows alert for "secure page browser cache" vulnerability. Below are the details of ZAP alert:

Risk: Medium
Reliability: Warning

**Description**: Secure page can be cached in browser.  Cache control is not set in HTTP header nor HTML header.  Sensitive content can be recovered from browser storage.

**Solution:** The best way is to set HTTP header with: 'Pragma: No-cache' and 'Cache-control: No-cache'. 
Alternatively, this can be set in the HTML header by: 
 
 
but some browsers may have problem using this method.

Can you please tell me how this vulnerability will affect my application if its not fixed and how an attacker will user it to hack the application.

Comment: You should close more of your questions

Comment: Any specific reason sir ? @Neil McGuigan

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that information that should be kept private can be viewed by anyone with access to the files in the browser's cache directory.

This is a problem particularly with shared computers.  If caching is not set properly, then anyone using the shared computer can view the private web pages after the original user has logged off the site which is hosting the secure material.

This can also be a problem if the computer has malware which can read files.  The malware can gather information from the browser cache and transfer it off the computer.

Your application will not malfunction if the cache headers are not set properly.  However, you might expose your users to the consequences of their private information being misused.